# Create all possible combinations of binomic variables in r

Tags: r, combinations

I have this dataset

```
install.packages("combinat")
install.packages("quantmod")
library(quantmod)
library(combinat)
getSymbols("AAPL",from="2013-01-01")
data<-AAPL
p1<-4  
dO<-data[,1]
dC<-data[,4]
emaO<-EMA(dO,n=p1)
emaC<-EMA(dC,n=p1)
```

and this variables

```
Pos_emaO_dO_UP<-emaO>dO
Pos_emaO_dO_D<-emaO<dO
Pos_emaC_dC_UP<-emaC>dC
Pos_emaC_dC_D<-emaC<dC
Pos_emaC_dO_D<-emaC<dO
Pos_emaC_dO_UP<-emaC>dO
Pos_emaO_dC_UP<-emaO>dC
Pos_emaO_dC_D<-emaO<dC
```

or alternatively

```
Pos_emaO_dO<-ifelse(emaO>dO,"UP",
                    ifelse(emaO<dO,"D","Equal"))
Pos_emaC_dC<-ifelse(emaC>dC,"UP",
                    ifelse(emaC<dC,"D","Equal"))
Pos_emaC_dO<-ifelse(emaC>dO,"UP",
                    ifelse(emaC<dO,"D","Equal"))
Pos_emaO_dC<-ifelse(emaO>dC,"UP",
                    ifelse(emaO<dC,"D","Equal"))



  frame<-data.frame(Pos_emaO_dO_UP,Pos_emaO_dO_D,Pos_emaC_dC_UP,Pos_emaC_dC_D,Pos_emaC_dO_D,Pos_emaC_dO_UP,Pos_emaO_dC_UP,Pos_emaO_dC_D)
    vector<-colnames(frame)<-c("Pos_emaO_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dC_UP","Pos_emaC_dC_D","Pos_emaC_dO_D","Pos_emaC_dO_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_UP","Pos_emaO_dC_D")
Three<-as.data.frame(combn(vector,3))
Two<-as.data.frame(combn(vector,2))
Four<-as.data.frame(combn(vector,4))
```

EDITED:
I edited my question to this. I need to delete these combinations (V1:Vn) which, for example, has both possible combinations of variable. e.x. Pos_emaO_dO_UP & Pos_emaO_dO_D. Generally, if the formula before D or UP is same and both (UP & D) are in it, delete this combination. I tried some unique, but with no success.

Note: I want then to use paste like paste(combination,collapse="&") and use this "pasted" combinations to subset the main table then like subset(main_table,"pasted_combination") and run this trough lapply function which I have. Will it works?
Thanks

Comment: Not sure I understand what combinations you _don't_ want included, but did you have a look at `expand.grid`? Perhaps it is helpful for you.

Comment: Yes, I looked at expand.grid but that is not what I need. I have n variables which can be UP or D or equal value (calculations above). And I need all possible combinations of them but there cannot be UP and D of each variable in combination (understand cannot be something UP and also D in same time). I need to make these combinations to use them to subset the main table to find the best possible combinations to evaluate the depend variable. Is it clear?

Comment: I edited to question, may be more clear.

Comment: In other words. I need to say unique function to compare just part of the name (without UP or D). And then I'll be able to delete these combinations which has less variables than others. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not quite sure if I understood you right, but consider this example. We have 3 variables (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`) and each of them can be either `Up` or `D` or `Equal`. To compute all possible combinations of the 3 variables, you can use `expand.grid`:

```
dd <- expand.grid(x1 = c("UP", "D", "Equal"), 
                  x2 = c("UP", "D", "Equal"), 
                  x3 = c("UP", "D", "Equal"))

dd
#      x1    x2    x3
#1     UP    UP    UP
#2      D    UP    UP
#3  Equal    UP    UP
#4     UP     D    UP
#5      D     D    UP
#6  Equal     D    UP
#7     UP Equal    UP
#8      D Equal    UP
#9  Equal Equal    UP
#10    UP    UP     D
#11     D    UP     D
#12 Equal    UP     D
#13    UP     D     D
#14     D     D     D
#15 Equal     D     D
#16    UP Equal     D
#17     D Equal     D
#18 Equal Equal     D
#19    UP    UP Equal
#20     D    UP Equal
#21 Equal    UP Equal
#22    UP     D Equal
#23     D     D Equal
#24 Equal     D Equal
#25    UP Equal Equal 
#26     D Equal Equal
#27 Equal Equal Equal
```

Now as far as I understood you, you want only those rows where `UP` and `D` are not *both* present. To do this, you could use `apply` to check in each row the appearance of `UP` and `D` and then select the correct rows.

```
#create a new column "check" and set 1 if "UP" AND "D" are present in row
dd$check <- apply(dd, 1, function(x) ifelse("UP" %in% x & "D" %in% x, 1 , 0))
```

The result is then:

```
> dd
#      x1    x2    x3 check
#1     UP    UP    UP     0
#2      D    UP    UP     1
#3  Equal    UP    UP     0
#4     UP     D    UP     1
#5      D     D    UP     1
#6  Equal     D    UP     1
#7     UP Equal    UP     0
#8      D Equal    UP     1
#9  Equal Equal    UP     0
#10    UP    UP     D     1
#11     D    UP     D     1
#12 Equal    UP     D     1
#13    UP     D     D     1
#14     D     D     D     0
#15 Equal     D     D     0
#16    UP Equal     D     1
#17     D Equal     D     0
#18 Equal Equal     D     0
#19    UP    UP Equal     0
#20     D    UP Equal     1
#21 Equal    UP Equal     0
#22    UP     D Equal     1
#23     D     D Equal     0
#24 Equal     D Equal     0
#25    UP Equal Equal     0
#26     D Equal Equal     0
#27 Equal Equal Equal     0
```

Now you can select all rows where `check` is 0.

```
dd <- dd[dd$check == 0,]
dd
#      x1    x2    x3   check
#1     UP    UP    UP       0
#3  Equal    UP    UP       0
#7     UP Equal    UP       0
#9  Equal Equal    UP       0
#14     D     D     D       0
#15 Equal     D     D       0
#17     D Equal     D       0      
#18 Equal Equal     D       0      
#19    UP    UP Equal       0      
#21 Equal    UP Equal       0      
#23     D     D Equal       0      
#24 Equal     D Equal       0      
#25    UP Equal Equal       0      
#26     D Equal Equal       0      
#27 Equal Equal Equal       0
```

Of course you can delete the extra column (already in the previous subsetting) or now:

```
dd <- dd[, -4]
```

Is that what you were after?

Comment: Yes, but it is not all. These are all possible combinations with 3 variables in subset (combination). I need also all possible combinations for 2,3,4,5,n ...combinations where n is number of variables. This should be done by combn, but I don't know exactly how. But thanks it helps me to look at t he problem a bit differently.